# How to check if NSDictionary is not nil in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting NSDictionary as parameter in my function but having problem because don't know how to check if that parameter is not nil.

My function looks like this:

```
func doSmth(val : NSDictionary)
```

Inside my function I'm trying to get some values:

```
let action = val["action"] as! String
```

But getting error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" when receive parameter val as nil.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is due to assuming (force casting) a value that can sometimes be nil. Swift is awesome, because it allows conditional unwraps and conditional casts in very concise statements. I recommend the following (for Swift 1-3):

Use "if let" to conditionally check for "action" in the dictionary.

Use as? to conditionally cast the value to a String

```
if let actionString = val["action"] as? String {
   // action is not nil, is a String type, and is now stored in actionString
} else {
   // action was either nil, or not a String type
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also access the `allKeys` or alternatively `allValues` property and check if the array contains any elements like so:

```
let dic = NSDictionary()
let total = dic.allKeys.count

    if total > 0 {

        // Something's in there

    }

    else {

        // Nothing in there
    }
```

**EDIT**

Here is how you can detect if the NSDictionary is nil, if they key you are looking for exists, and if it does attempt to access it's value:

```
let yourKey = "yourKey"

if let dic = response.someDictionary as? NSDictionary {
    // We've got a live one. NSDictionary is valid.

    // Check the existence of key - OR check dic.allKeys.containsObject(yourKey).
    let keyExists: Bool = false;
    for var key as String in dic.allKeys {

        if key == yourKey {
            keyExists = true;
        }
    }

    // If yourKey exists, access it's possible value.
    if keyExists == true {

       // Access your value
        if let value = dic[yourKey] as? AnyObject {
             // We're in business. We have the value!
        }

        else {
            // yourKey does not contain a value.
        }

    }

    else {
        // yourKey does not exist in NSDictionary.
    }

}

else {
    // Call an ambulance. NSDictionary is nil.
}
```

Comment: "dic.allKeys.count" was what I was after. Thanks!

Comment: This answers the question title, but not the question body. The question referred specifically to checking a particular parameter in the Dictionary. However, this solution is useful for many other cases regarding dictionary checking.

Comment: I hear what you are saying, but MangtasG said he was having problems "because don't know how to check if that parameter is not nil". The parameter he was referring to was of type NSDictionary. In my answer I demonstrated how to check if an NSDictionary is nil via checking if there are any keys. I believe this is the best way to tell if you have a valid NSDictionary. However, I only specify "Nothing in there" in my comments. I will update my answer to reflect the connection between my answer and the problem MangtasG was having.

Comment: Hey Brandon, just wanted to follow up on this because it floated back up to the top of my comments. It's technically not necessarily efficient to cycle through keys to check for existence. Dictionaries (and Sets despite an interviewer at Google telling me otherwise) are backed by hashing for unique checks. also means lookups are O[1] :)

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary parameter is probably not nil. The problem is probably that your dictionary doesn't contain a value for the key `"action"`.

When you say `val["action"]`, the dictionary (being an `NSDictionary`) returns an `Optional<AnyObject>`.  If `val` contains the key `"action"`, it returns `Some(value)`. If `val` doesn't contain the key `"action"`, it returns `None`, which is the same as nil.

You can unwrap the `Optional`  in your cast, and choose a course of action based on whether it was nil, using an `if-let` statement:

```
if let action = val["action"] as? String {
    // action is a String, not an Optional<String>
} else {
    // The dictionary doesn't contain the key "action", and
    // action isn't declared in this scope.
}
```

If you really think `val` itself might be nil, you need to declare your function that way, and you can unwrap `val` without renaming it using a somewhat confusing `guard` statement:

```
func doSmth(val: NSDictionary?) {
    guard let val = val else {
        // If val vas passed in as nil, I get here.
        return
    }

    // val is now an NSDictionary, not an Optional<NSDictionary>.
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, never run across the guard statement before... I'll look into this one for academic purposes :)

Comment: I believe there is one incorrect point in the comment: // The dictionary doesn't contain the key "action"

As written with val["action"] as? String, the "as?" conditionally casts val["action"] to a String. This means, there may indeed exist a key for "action" in the val dictionary, but it is a class other than String. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

That's not particularly related to Swift 2.

If the dictionary could be `nil` declare it as optional

```
func doSmth(val : NSDictionary?)
```

Then use optional bindings to check

```
if let valIsNonOptional = val {
  let action = valIsNonOptional["action"] as! String
}
```

The code assumes that there is a key `action` containing a `String` value anyway if the dictionary is not nil